# What is this weird code?

Tags: javascript

I have stumbled across this code:

```
"⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭⁭".length
```

It should obviously return 0, but for some reason returns 1337. Is this some kind of trick i dont know?

Comment: Did you *intentionally* put 1337 invisible characters in there? (specifically, [U+206D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/206d/index.htm))

Comment: It **is** zero! http://jsfiddle.net/6CPK4/ or maybe not! http://jsfiddle.net/6CPK4/1/

Comment: i would say the expected result is weird

Comment: @MatteoTassinari this is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6CPK4/2/) with the OP's string copy/pasted into it. It shows the 1337 length.

Comment: @lurker I had created one too.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to lose reputation

Comment: @Dvidunis Where did that `""` string come from? It's obviously not a blank string as it has non-displayable characters in it.

Comment: The effect is kind of ruined when your browser fails to perform font substitution and instead renders 1337 little "unknown character" boxes XD

Comment: Why did someone upvote this question?!?!

Comment: I JUST FOUND THIS ON THE INTERNET!!! WHY IS EVERYONE SO ANGRY?

Comment: @Dvidunis Welcome to StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is:

- Open quote
- [Unicode Character 'ACTIVATE ARABIC FORM SHAPING' (U+206D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/206d/index.htm) ×1337
- Close quote
- `.length`

Since the string is made of 1337 "invisible" characters, the length is 1337.

Comment: Thank you for not being mean!

Comment: @Dvidunis Downvoting != being mean. It just means your question kinda sucks :p

Comment: I meant the comments..